# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException - Intermittent issue (2+ out of est. 100k transactions encounters this error daily)

Tags: java, spring, cics

We are using springframework 5.2.3 on a J2EE app over zOS.

The flow starts as follows:

1. API is consumed in zOS via URIMAP configuration, which underlying triggers an OSGi program (Bridge) which is in Java.
2. Bridge will perform CICS link to POJO class in CICS via main method, hence, POJO will have to rely on web application context to get bean instead of Autowire.
3. Main method in CICS will attempt to retrieve XController via the following:

In XRController, line 120:

```
private XController xController = AppContext.getApplicationContext().getBean(XController.class);
```

In AppContext:

```
public class AppContext {
       
       /** Shared application context for the entire environment */
       private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;
       
       /** Id of the context for the entire environment */
       private static String contextId;
       
       /**
       * Retrieve of current application context based on the 
        * respective war file
       * 
        * @return the current web application context
       */
       public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
              ApplicationContext context = ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
              
              if (context != null) {
                     if (contextId == null || !contextId.equalsIgnoreCase(context.getId())) {
                           applicationContext = context;
                           contextId  = context.getId();
                     }
              }
              
              return applicationContext;
       }
}
```

In XController:

```
@Controller
@Scope("prototype")
public class XController extends OController {
...
```

In root-context.xml:

```
..
<!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Component @Service @Entity classes to configure as beans -->
<context:component-scan base-package="c.a.b." />
..
```

4. However, out of 100k+ transactions each day, several transactions encounters the following error:

```
[1/9/22 15:40:29:568 GMT+08:00] 00000075 LogService-147-com.ibm.cics.wlp.link.impl                    E CWWKE0701E: [com.ibm.cics.wlp.link.impl.connector] [CICSMessageWorker] @Error: handleException() - Exception org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'c.a.b.b.x.c.XController' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1126)
    at c.a.b.b.x.b.XRController.<init>(XRController.java:120)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.invocation.proxy.LinkBean_362be17e6965b072ec596a5c6949dde3.doInvoke(InstanceInvocationProxyTemplate.java:39)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.invocation.proxy.LinkBean_362be17e6965b072ec596a5c6949dde3.invoke(InstanceInvocationProxyTemplate.java:28)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.invocation.proxy.EJSLocalNSLLinkBean_362be17e6965b072ec596a5_cd6e4e37.invoke(EJSLocalNSLLinkBean_362be17e6965b072ec596a5_cd6e4e37.java)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.link.impl.ProxiedPOJOLinkableTarget.invoke(ProxiedPOJOLinkableTarget.java:135)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.link.impl.LinkableServicesManagerImpl.invoke(LinkableServicesManagerImpl.java:448)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ws.context.service.serializable.ContextualInvocationHandler.invoke(ContextualInvocationHandler.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.context.service.serializable.ContextualInvocationHandler.invoke(ContextualInvocationHandler.java:99)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.link.impl.connector.CICSMessageWorker.run(CICSMessageWorker.java:187)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.inbound.security.JCASecurityContextService$1.run(JCASecurityContextService.java:37)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.inbound.security.JCASecurityContextService$1.run(JCASecurityContextService.java:34)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:708)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:490)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:123)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.inbound.security.JCASecurityContextService$2.run(JCASecurityContextService.java:44)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.inbound.security.JCASecurityContextService$2.run(JCASecurityContextService.java:41)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:682)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.inbound.security.JCASecurityContextService.runInInboundSecurityContext(JCASecurityContextService.java:41)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.internal.WorkProxy.run(WorkProxy.java:356)
    at com.ibm.ws.context.service.serializable.ContextualRunnable.run(ContextualRunnable.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.internal.WorkProxy.call(WorkProxy.java:287)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.internal.WorkProxy.call(WorkProxy.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.ExecutorServiceImpl$RunnableWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceImpl.java:238)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.threading.CICSThread.run(CICSThread.java:269)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.threading.CICSPooledThreadFactory.joinAsThreadInternal(CICSPooledThreadFactory.java:426)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.threading.CICSPooledThreadFactory.joinAsThread(CICSPooledThreadFactory.java:352)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.internal.ThreadJoiner.main(ThreadJoiner.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.Wrapper.call_main(Wrapper.java:947)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.Wrapper.callOSGiClass(Wrapper.java:2912)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.Wrapper.invokeJvmServerOSGiClass(Wrapper.java:2778)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.Wrapper.jvmServerOSGiEntry(Wrapper.java:2707)
    at com.ibm.cics.osgi.bundlepart.impl.CICSOSGiBundlepartControllerImpl.runService(CICSOSGiBundlepartControllerImpl.java:1284)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.bundlepart.impl.CICSLibertyBundlepartControllerImpl.runService(CICSLibertyBundlepartControllerImpl.java:975)
    at com.ibm.cics.osgi.impl.Controller.runService(Controller.java:782)
    at com.ibm.cics.osgi.impl.Controller.acceptRequest(Controller.java:282)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.cics.router.Router.route(Router.java:1373)
  
[1/9/22 15:40:29:627 GMT+08:00] 00017616 SystemErr                                                    R 2022/01/09 15:40:29.565000 GMT+08:00 E [BFWXCJ2.TASK49772.BY02:117] [com.ibm.cics.wlp.link.impl.connector] [CICSMessageWorker] @Error: handleException() - Exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'c.a.b.b.x.c.XController' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1126)
    at c.a.b.b.x.b.XRController.<init>(XRController.java:120)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.invocation.proxy.LinkBean_362be17e6965b072ec596a5c6949dde3.doInvoke(InstanceInvocationProxyTemplate.java:39)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.invocation.proxy.LinkBean_362be17e6965b072ec596a5c6949dde3.invoke(InstanceInvocationProxyTemplate.java:28)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.invocation.proxy.EJSLocalNSLLinkBean_362be17e6965b072ec596a5_cd6e4e37.invoke(EJSLocalNSLLinkBean_362be17e6965b072ec596a5_cd6e4e37.java)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.link.impl.ProxiedPOJOLinkableTarget.invoke(ProxiedPOJOLinkableTarget.java:135)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.link.impl.LinkableServicesManagerImpl.invoke(LinkableServicesManagerImpl.java:448)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ws.context.service.serializable.ContextualInvocationHandler.invoke(ContextualInvocationHandler.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.context.service.serializable.ContextualInvocationHandler.invoke(ContextualInvocationHandler.java:99)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.link.impl.connector.CICSMessageWorker.run(CICSMessageWorker.java:187)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.inbound.security.JCASecurityContextService$1.run(JCASecurityContextService.java:37)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.inbound.security.JCASecurityContextService$1.run(JCASecurityContextService.java:34)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:708)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:490)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:123)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.inbound.security.JCASecurityContextService$2.run(JCASecurityContextService.java:44)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.inbound.security.JCASecurityContextService$2.run(JCASecurityContextService.java:41)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:682)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.inbound.security.JCASecurityContextService.runInInboundSecurityContext(JCASecurityContextService.java:41)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.internal.WorkProxy.run(WorkProxy.java:356)
    at com.ibm.ws.context.service.serializable.ContextualRunnable.run(ContextualRunnable.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.internal.WorkProxy.call(WorkProxy.java:287)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.internal.WorkProxy.call(WorkProxy.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.ExecutorServiceImpl$RunnableWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceImpl.java:238)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.threading.CICSThread.run(CICSThread.java:269)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.threading.CICSPooledThreadFactory.joinAsThreadInternal(CICSPooledThreadFactory.java:426)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.threading.CICSPooledThreadFactory.joinAsThread(CICSPooledThreadFactory.java:352)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.internal.ThreadJoiner.main(ThreadJoiner.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.Wrapper.call_main(Wrapper.java:947)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.Wrapper.callOSGiClass(Wrapper.java:2912)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.Wrapper.invokeJvmServerOSGiClass(Wrapper.java:2778)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.Wrapper.jvmServerOSGiEntry(Wrapper.java:2707)
    at com.ibm.cics.osgi.bundlepart.impl.CICSOSGiBundlepartControllerImpl.runService(CICSOSGiBundlepartControllerImpl.java:1284)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.bundlepart.impl.CICSLibertyBundlepartControllerImpl.runService(CICSLibertyBundlepartControllerImpl.java:975)
    at com.ibm.cics.osgi.impl.Controller.runService(Controller.java:782)
    at com.ibm.cics.osgi.impl.Controller.acceptRequest(Controller.java:282)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.cics.router.Router.route(Router.java:1373)
[1/9/22 15:40:29:630 GMT+08:00] 00017615 SystemOut                                                    O XC Bridge Error: CICS_ABEND (AJ05)
[1/9/22 15:40:29:685 GMT+08:00] 00000075 com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.RuntimeException: AJ05 com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject 124" at ffdc_22.01.09_15.40.29.0.log
[1/9/22 15:40:29:689 GMT+08:00] 00000075 LogService-147-com.ibm.cics.wlp.link.impl                    E CWWKE0701E: [com.ibm.cics.wlp.link.impl.connector] [CICSMessageWorkAdapter] @Error: processWorkEvent() - Error occurred while processing com.ibm.cics.wlp.link.impl.connector.CICSMessageWorker@245b4b29 javax.resource.spi.work.WorkCompletedException: java.lang.RuntimeException: AJ05, error code: 0
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.internal.WorkProxy.call(WorkProxy.java:297)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.internal.WorkProxy.call(WorkProxy.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.ExecutorServiceImpl$RunnableWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceImpl.java:238)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.threading.CICSThread.run(CICSThread.java:269)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.threading.CICSPooledThreadFactory.joinAsThreadInternal(CICSPooledThreadFactory.java:426)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.threading.CICSPooledThreadFactory.joinAsThread(CICSPooledThreadFactory.java:352)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.internal.ThreadJoiner.main(ThreadJoiner.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.Wrapper.call_main(Wrapper.java:947)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.Wrapper.callOSGiClass(Wrapper.java:2912)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.Wrapper.invokeJvmServerOSGiClass(Wrapper.java:2778)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.Wrapper.jvmServerOSGiEntry(Wrapper.java:2707)
    at com.ibm.cics.osgi.bundlepart.impl.CICSOSGiBundlepartControllerImpl.runService(CICSOSGiBundlepartControllerImpl.java:1284)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.bundlepart.impl.CICSLibertyBundlepartControllerImpl.runService(CICSLibertyBundlepartControllerImpl.java:975)
    at com.ibm.cics.osgi.impl.Controller.runService(Controller.java:782)
    at com.ibm.cics.osgi.impl.Controller.acceptRequest(Controller.java:282)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.cics.router.Router.route(Router.java:1373)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: AJ05
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:127)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.inbound.security.JCASecurityContextService$2.run(JCASecurityContextService.java:44)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.inbound.security.JCASecurityContextService$2.run(JCASecurityContextService.java:41)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:682)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.inbound.security.JCASecurityContextService.runInInboundSecurityContext(JCASecurityContextService.java:41)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.internal.WorkProxy.run(WorkProxy.java:356)
    at com.ibm.ws.context.service.serializable.ContextualRunnable.run(ContextualRunnable.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.internal.WorkProxy.call(WorkProxy.java:287)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: AJ05
    at com.ibm.cics.server.Wrapper.handleReturnCode(Wrapper.java:1295)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.link.impl.connector.CICSMessageWorker.handleException(CICSMessageWorker.java:431)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.link.impl.connector.CICSMessageWorker.run(CICSMessageWorker.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.inbound.security.JCASecurityContextService$1.run(JCASecurityContextService.java:37)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.inbound.security.JCASecurityContextService$1.run(JCASecurityContextService.java:34)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:708)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:490)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:123)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'c.a.b.b.x.c.XController' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1126)
    at c.a.b.b.x.b.XRController.<init>(XRController.java:120)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.invocation.proxy.LinkBean_362be17e6965b072ec596a5c6949dde3.doInvoke(InstanceInvocationProxyTemplate.java:39)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.invocation.proxy.LinkBean_362be17e6965b072ec596a5c6949dde3.invoke(InstanceInvocationProxyTemplate.java:28)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.invocation.proxy.EJSLocalNSLLinkBean_362be17e6965b072ec596a5_cd6e4e37.invoke(EJSLocalNSLLinkBean_362be17e6965b072ec596a5_cd6e4e37.java)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.link.impl.ProxiedPOJOLinkableTarget.invoke(ProxiedPOJOLinkableTarget.java:135)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.link.impl.LinkableServicesManagerImpl.invoke(LinkableServicesManagerImpl.java:448)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ws.context.service.serializable.ContextualInvocationHandler.invoke(ContextualInvocationHandler.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.context.service.serializable.ContextualInvocationHandler.invoke(ContextualInvocationHandler.java:99)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.link.impl.connector.CICSMessageWorker.run(CICSMessageWorker.java:187)
    ... 39 more
  
[1/9/22 15:40:29:705 GMT+08:00] 00017619 SystemErr                                                    R 2022/01/09 15:40:29.688000 GMT+08:00 E [RUN_SERVICE_Thread-49:117] [com.ibm.cics.wlp.link.impl.connector] [CICSMessageWorkAdapter] @Error: processWorkEvent() - Error occurred while processing com.ibm.cics.wlp.link.impl.connector.CICSMessageWorker@245b4b29
javax.resource.spi.work.WorkCompletedException: java.lang.RuntimeException: AJ05, error code: 0
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.internal.WorkProxy.call(WorkProxy.java:297)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.internal.WorkProxy.call(WorkProxy.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.ExecutorServiceImpl$RunnableWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceImpl.java:238)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.threading.CICSThread.run(CICSThread.java:269)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.threading.CICSPooledThreadFactory.joinAsThreadInternal(CICSPooledThreadFactory.java:426)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.threading.CICSPooledThreadFactory.joinAsThread(CICSPooledThreadFactory.java:352)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.internal.ThreadJoiner.main(ThreadJoiner.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.Wrapper.call_main(Wrapper.java:947)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.Wrapper.callOSGiClass(Wrapper.java:2912)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.Wrapper.invokeJvmServerOSGiClass(Wrapper.java:2778)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.Wrapper.jvmServerOSGiEntry(Wrapper.java:2707)
    at com.ibm.cics.osgi.bundlepart.impl.CICSOSGiBundlepartControllerImpl.runService(CICSOSGiBundlepartControllerImpl.java:1284)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.bundlepart.impl.CICSLibertyBundlepartControllerImpl.runService(CICSLibertyBundlepartControllerImpl.java:975)
    at com.ibm.cics.osgi.impl.Controller.runService(Controller.java:782)
    at com.ibm.cics.osgi.impl.Controller.acceptRequest(Controller.java:282)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.cics.router.Router.route(Router.java:1373)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: AJ05
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:127)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.inbound.security.JCASecurityContextService$2.run(JCASecurityContextService.java:44)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.inbound.security.JCASecurityContextService$2.run(JCASecurityContextService.java:41)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:682)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.inbound.security.JCASecurityContextService.runInInboundSecurityContext(JCASecurityContextService.java:41)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.internal.WorkProxy.run(WorkProxy.java:356)
    at com.ibm.ws.context.service.serializable.ContextualRunnable.run(ContextualRunnable.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.internal.WorkProxy.call(WorkProxy.java:287)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: AJ05
    at com.ibm.cics.server.Wrapper.handleReturnCode(Wrapper.java:1295)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.link.impl.connector.CICSMessageWorker.handleException(CICSMessageWorker.java:431)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.link.impl.connector.CICSMessageWorker.run(CICSMessageWorker.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.inbound.security.JCASecurityContextService$1.run(JCASecurityContextService.java:37)
    at com.ibm.ws.jca.inbound.security.JCASecurityContextService$1.run(JCASecurityContextService.java:34)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:708)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:490)
    at com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.doAs(WSSubject.java:123)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'c.a.b.b.x.c.XController' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1126)
    at c.a.b.b.x.b.XRController.<init>(XRController.java:120)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.invocation.proxy.LinkBean_362be17e6965b072ec596a5c6949dde3.doInvoke(InstanceInvocationProxyTemplate.java:39)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.invocation.proxy.LinkBean_362be17e6965b072ec596a5c6949dde3.invoke(InstanceInvocationProxyTemplate.java:28)
    at com.ibm.cics.server.invocation.proxy.EJSLocalNSLLinkBean_362be17e6965b072ec596a5_cd6e4e37.invoke(EJSLocalNSLLinkBean_362be17e6965b072ec596a5_cd6e4e37.java)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.link.impl.ProxiedPOJOLinkableTarget.invoke(ProxiedPOJOLinkableTarget.java:135)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.link.impl.LinkableServicesManagerImpl.invoke(LinkableServicesManagerImpl.java:448)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ws.context.service.serializable.ContextualInvocationHandler.invoke(ContextualInvocationHandler.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.context.service.serializable.ContextualInvocationHandler.invoke(ContextualInvocationHandler.java:99)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.cics.wlp.link.impl.connector.CICSMessageWorker.run(CICSMessageWorker.java:187)
    ... 39 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Linking to Java EE POJOs can mean some of the contextual information isn't available during the link. I can't say for sure why the problem is intermittent (the error appears to be coming from the Spring framework, which is something the CICS team doesn't have control over), but I can suggest some ways which could avoid the issue.

1. In CICS TS v5.5 we added support for linking to Spring Boot applications directly: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.5?topic=ljesbafcp-preparing-spring-boot-application-be-called-by-cics-program this allows you to use Spring bean injection (`@Autowired`, etc.) in methods annotated `@CICSProgram`.
2. Alternatively you could be to investigate routing parts of your API directly into the Spring application over HTTP. Coming into CICS via HTTP then linking to OSGi and then to Liberty is going to have increased CPU usage and complexity compared to coming into the Spring application hosted in Liberty via HTTP.

Spring boot applications are supported in CICS TS v5.4: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.4?topic=server-spring-boot-applications and we have a number of samples which demonstrate how to integrate these applications with CICS, with regards to JCICS, security and transactionality available on github: https://github.com/cicsdev.